# How to prove $\alpha =\{1, x,...,x^n\}$ is a basis for $P_n(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, vectors

Let $v=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$, if $a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n=0$, then all coefficient $a_i\in F$ are $0$ as variables are all with different degrees so it is linearly independent (Here I am no sure how to correctly prove it). In addition, although the span looks apparent, but I am still not sure how to show that. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. To show that the set is linearly independent, recall that two polynomials are the same iff their coefficients are the same.
2. Showing that the set spans $P_n(F)$ is almost tautological: We already usually write a general polynomial of degree $\leq n$ as $a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$, which in particular is already written as a linear combination of basis elements.

Answer (score 0):

For linearly independence, you can use that Vander Monde matrices are invertible.

And now $p(x)$ be any polynomial in $P_n[X]$. We can write $p(x)$ in terms of the elements of the basis (monomials) by

$p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$

where $a_i = \frac{p^{(i)}(0)}{i!}$.